# Split and implode a list of tuples by specific characters using list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples on the following format

```
l =[('A-B','X'),
  ('A-C','X'),
  ('A-D','X'),
  ('E-F','Y'),
  ('E-G','Y')]
```

Which I want to implode by splitting the first element on `-` and then apply list comprehension to the following format

```
[('A',['B','C','D'],'X'),
('E',['F','G'],'Y')]
```

I know there should be an easy one liner to do this using list comprehension but have a hard time understanding how to get split the list of tuples and compress into a list. 
Something like

```
 [(x[0].split("-")[0], ..... , x[1]) for x in l]
```

EDIT:

Removed a faulty `[`

Comment: I would suggest you to try first without comprehension and then see how to convert it.

Comment: Removed the faulty `[`

Comment: For a one-linear I can only think of usin groupby here. But that would only work if the starting letters are consecutive?

Comment: There is no easy one liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`, `itertools.groupby()` and `str.split()` to get to it:

```
l =[('A-B','X'),
  ('A-C','X'),
  ('A-D','X'),
  ('E-F','Y'),
  ('E-G','Y')]

r = [(a, list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([c[1:-1] for c in y])), b)
    for (a, b), y in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split('-') for x in y)) for y in l),
        key=lambda x: (x[0], x[-1]))]
print(r)
# [('A', ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'X'), ('E', ['F', 'G'], 'Y')]
```

Firstly, "flatten" the string inside the tuple, then I use `groupby` to get to the 
base sub-items for the results. Within that, I use again `groupby` to get all the potential "middle elements" as a flatten list.

The code include some choices that are not specified in the question, e.g.:

- I assume that both the first result of the split and the last item of the tuple are significant for the grouping
- I assume the input can be sorted by the first item for the grouping to be effecting
- I assume that the result of the `str.split()` may yield more than 2 items

With different assumptions, one may get to different and perhaps simpler results.

---

On a personal note, I would not wish my worst fiend to debug code like this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. On the assumptions, the split will only return 2 items. Also, on that personal note, do you have an suggestion on how to make it easier? How would you do this personally?

Comment: @kspr The code *per se* is OK, but it is hard to read. And possibly it could be made more efficient. There is no particular advantage in having this in one line. I would write it in more lines, trying to pick better names for the dummy variables and including comments to explain the why's and the assumptions of the code. I would need some more context to propose some code fulfilling all this. For Example, yatu's now deleted code was much easier to read and probably more efficient.